# Sunspot Solr email search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am using the sunspot gem which uses solr. I have been struggling for a couple of days now trying to get my use cases working for searching one field.

I have a table with an "email" column in it. All i'm trying to do is get it to return substring matches as well as full matches.

For example given the email:

bob@gmail.com

I want to be able to match this with all of the following:

- bob
- b@gm
- gmail
- gmail.com
- .com
- bob@gmail.com

basically any 3 chars that are a match should be returned.

The problems I am having is that the full match will not work with default config. "bob@gmail.com" does not return any results because it splits at the @ sign and searches for bob gmail.com and does not find it.

If i search  for gmail.com etc. it will work. Or if I search for bob it will also work.

So I've tried probably half a dozen suggestions that i've found on similar posts, and have gotten a couple of them to get the full match to work, but then the partial matches no longer work.

Here is what i've got now in the schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="40"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="40"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I am using the solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory tokenizer to match email addresses since the @ symbol is a problem. I've also tried just simply escaping the @ symbol in my search (bob\@gmail.com) and tried double quoting ("bob@gmail.com") and none of those work either. So the only two tokenizers that i've got to match the full email is UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory and also KeyWordTokenizer, but both of them break the partial matching.

This is my first stab at ever using solr, so talk to me like I know nothing :)

Thanks!